# Using same margin-settings in acronym as in listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, acronyms

As the two pictures show, the first entry of `listoffigures` begins further to the right than in the case of my list of abbreviations. Is it - and if yes, how - possible to retrieve the margin-settings used in the `listoffigures`-environment and to apply these to the `acronym`-environment?

[image: ListOfAbbr]
[image: listoffigures]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{3PL}{Third-party logistics}
\acro{APS}{Advanced Planning and Scheduling}
\end{acronym}

\listoffigures

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{Section}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
       \centering
       \includegraphics{example.png} 
       \caption{example caption}
       \label{fig:example1}
    \end{figure}
    \index{Figure!Example1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can go with `xpatch` and `enumitem`, since the package realizes the list of acronyms as a `description` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xpatch,enumitem}
\usepackage{acronym}

\xpatchcmd{\acronym}{\begin{description}}
 {\begin{description}[labelindent=1.5em]}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{3PL}{Third-party logistics}
\acro{APS}{Advanced Planning and Scheduling}
\end{acronym}

...
```

[image]

The amount of indentation in the list of figures is stored in the macro `\l@figure` which usually has a definition such as

```
\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{2.3em}
```

If you use a class where the definition is this, then a workaround to avoid guessing the length is as follows

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xpatch,enumitem}
\usepackage{acronym}

\newlength\lfigureindent
\xpatchcmd{\acronym}{\begin{description}}
 {\begin{description}[labelindent=\lfigureindent]}{}{}
\makeatletter
\def\get@l@figure@indent{\expandafter\get@l@figure@indentaux\l@figure}
\def\get@l@figure@indentaux#1#2#3#4{\lfigureindent=#3\relax}
\AtBeginDocument{\get@l@figure@indent}
\makeatother
```

However, this can fail if some package (or class) changes the definition of `\l@figure`. Unfortunately there is no parameter for that length.

Comment: Please see my comment to GonzaloMedina's answer.

Answer (score 2):

One quick fix would be to use a list to wrap the acronym environment and use the desired indention; this can be easily done with the help of the [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\makeindex

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of abbreviations}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5em}{}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{3PL}{Third-party logistics}
\acro{APS}{Advanced Planning and Scheduling}
\end{acronym}
\end{adjustwidth}

\listoffigures

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{Section}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
       \centering
       \includegraphics{example.png} 
       \caption{example caption}
       \label{fig:example1}
    \end{figure}
    \index{Figure!Example1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If one changes the `documentclass` the value of 1.5em may change. So instead of setting a fix value the might be the possibility to have a dynamic value: Is it possible to retrieve the indention from the `listoffigures`-environment so that the indention of my list of abbreviations will be always the same as in `listoffigures` no matter which changes will be made in the preamble?

Comment: @John since the indentation is given in the first argument of `\@dotedtocline` in `\l@figure` and the standard classes all use `1.5em` for this value, is pretty safe to use it here; besides, if a package changes `\l@figure` I don't think there's a robust way to capture the new assigned value.